# como pasar de números a letras?

Tags: java, mvc

Tengo una tarea en la cual debo pasar de números a letras por ejemplo yo ingreso el numero 5 en un formulario y me devuelve "cinco", ahora bien necesito usar el mvc pero no se si existe alguna libreria que me premita hacer eso?? realmente no le llego a la logica, apenas es mi primera clase usando el patron mvc

Comment: Deberías formular la pregunta de manera adecuada. Por ejemplo, exponer el problema, poner un ejemplo con input/output, algo de código que nos permita saber como estas tratando el problema... Hay una sección entera destinada a hacer una buena pregunta. La comunidad está encantada respondiendo siempre y cuando la formulación sea la correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Algo muy simple seria crear una listas con la parte del numero que siempre se repiten y de ahi en adelante jugar con un poco de aritmetica para evaluar si el numero es una unidad o decena.

Te dejo este simple programa que puede evaluar numeros entre 0 y 99 evidentemente se puede hacer mucho mejor pero eso te lo dejo a ti :)

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i=0;i<=99;i++){
            System.out.println(convertirNumeroATexto(i));
        }

    }

    public static String convertirNumeroATexto(int numero) {
        String unidades[] = new String[]{"cero", "uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco", "seis",
                "siete", "ocho", "nueve"};

        String especiales[] = new String[]{"diez","once", "doce", "trece", "catorce", "quince", "dieciseis",
                "diecisiete", "dieciocho", "diecinueve"};

        String decenas[] = new String[]{ "veinte", "treinta", "cuarenta", "cincuenta", "sesenta",
                "setenta", "ochenta", "noventa"};

        if (numero < 10) {
            return unidades[numero];
        }
        if (numero < 20) {
            return especiales[numero - 10];
        }
        if (numero < 100 && numero % 10 == 0) {
            int index = (numero / 10) - 2;
            return decenas[index];
        }

        if(numero<100){
            int dIndex = (numero/10)-2;
            int uIndex = (numero%10);
            return decenas[dIndex] + " y " + unidades[uIndex];
        }
        //si retorna null es porque el numero  no es valido
        return null;
    }
}
```

Salida

```
cero
uno
dos
tres
cuatro
cinco
seis
siete
ocho
nueve
diez
once
doce
trece
catorce
quince
dieciseis
diecisiete
dieciocho
diecinueve
veinte
veinte y uno
veinte y dos
veinte y tres
.....
```

Edit: Me quede con la duda de como se escriben los numeros apartir del veinte (lo se soy un inculto) y en muchos foros parece que la forma como yo lo escribo es incorrecto, igual espero el programa te pueda ayudar y si no es la correcta forma de escribir puedes modificar el programa para adaptarlo, tampoco es tan difícil. :)